# Sum values for a specific period

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some IDs, dates and Values. 
I want to sum values for each ID for the last 10 days.

This code can reproduce my dataset:

```
date<-as.Date(c("05/03/2017","05/10/2017","05/14/2017","05/19/2017","05/22/2017"),format="%m/%d/%Y")
value<-rpois(20,50)
id<-NULL
for(i in 1:4){id<-c(id,rep(i,5))}

mydata<-data.frame(id,date=rep(date,4),value)
```

So, the output would be the dataset above with a new column. This column would have the sum of values of lasts 10 days.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are the last 10 days defined? Starting at the earliest date in the data?

Comment: Fwiw, there's `library(data.table); setDT(mydata); mydata[, v := .SD[.(id = id, d_dn = date - 10, d_up = date), on=.(id, date >= d_dn, date < d_up), sum(value), by=.EACHI]$V1]` I guess there is a dupe of this post somewhere..

Comment: It depends on each "date" value in the row. Example: for the 3rd row, date=2017-05-14, so 10 days would be from 2017-05-05 until 2017-05-14.

Comment: So your sum will differ within each group? Sounds like @Frank's solution should work perfectly for this

Comment: Yes, each row has one different sum, because depends on date and ids. @Frank solution fits perfect!